# How to write mod rewrite to serve @2x images from different path?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use Drupal 7 to manage the content for an iOS app.  I can setup Drupal to create retina (@2x) size and non-retina size images.  Rather than update the app to get @2x images from a different path, I would like to use mod rewrite if possible to serve @2x images from a different folder.

For example, the path to non-retina images are:
    /sites/default/files/styles/`large`/public/flyers/OfficialSchedule.jpg?itok=qGpDKWpr

I would like the request for OfficialSchedule@2x.jpg to come from:
    /sites/default/files/styles/`retina`/public/flyers/OfficialSchedule.jpg?itok=qGpDKWpr

Is this possible?

***Result: Thanks to @jerdiggity***

I had to add `$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;` to my settings file for Drupal 7.20 and higher to allow images to be requested without adding the token value.

```
# NOTES: Check the file name to see if it matches the @2x pattern:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)(@2x\.\w+)$ [NC]

# NOTES: This may or may not be necessary, depending on your desired results (uncomment if so):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/sites/default/files/styles/regular/public/flyer/) [NC]

# NOTES: Rewrite everything with @2x, but don't rewrite requests to the /sites/default/files/styles/retina/public/flyer/ directory (duplicate rewrites)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/sites/default/files/styles/retina/public/flyer/) [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)@2x\.(\w+) /sites/default/files/styles/retina/public/flyer/$1\.$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it via using an absolute path to the file location...

This assumes your site is installed at `/home/mydrupalsite`:

```
# NOTES: Check the file name to see if it matches the @2x pattern:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)(@2x\.jpg)$ [NC]

# NOTES: This may or may not be necessary, depending on your desired results (uncomment if so):
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/flyers/) [NC]

# NOTES: Rewrite everything with @2x, but don't rewrite requests to the /sites/default/files/styles/retina/public/flyers/ directory (duplicate rewrites)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/sites/default/files/styles/retina/public/flyers/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)@2x\.jpg /home/mydrupalsite/sites/default/files/styles/retina/public/flyers/$1\.jpg [L,R=301]
```

Hope that helps... :)

Comment: No luck so far but I am going to try and log mod_rewrite to see why.  Right now I am getting the error "Error generating image." which tells me that it might not even get to the rules.

Comment: Got it!  I had to modify the rewrite rule to only pull the file name.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)@2x\.jpg =>> RewriteRule (\w*)@2x\.jpg

It was copying the path and adding it to the end of the url.  I also did not need to include the absolute path for the file.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @sho Cool! Out of curiosity, what did the final `RewriteRule` look like?

Comment: Posted it above in the original question.  Was too long for a comment.  I tested it online and it works perfectly but have not tested it with my app yet.  I get the resized image but the path also changes so I'm waiting to see if the app is ok with this.